How to add port on kubeflow pipeline in kfpv2?
kfp == 2.8.0
kfp-kubernetes == 1.2.0
@dsl.component()
def server():
    ....

@dsl.pipeline()
def my_pipeline():
    server_task=server()
    server_task.add_port(V1ContainerPort(name='my-port', container_port=8080))

---> server_task.add_port(V1ContainerPort(name='my-port', container_port=8080))
AttributeError: 'PipelineTask' object has no attribute 'add_port'
In kfpv1 the code can work, but in kfpv2 'add_port' had been removed. Is there any method to add port on task ?
